# How to get particular amount of records from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app there are many records (let's suppose 100 records) available in sqlite. What I want is to get last 50 records from database. And I am using below code for this purpose.

```
String [] projection = new String[]{
            ID, MESSAGE_ID, MESSAGE_TYPE, MESSAGE_MEDIA_STATUS, MESSAGE_BODY, MESSAGE_MEDIA_REFERENCE,
            MESSAGE_MEDIA_TYPE, MESSAGE_MEDIA_SIZE, MESSAGE_SENDER_ID, MESSAGE_RECIPIENT_ID,
            MESSAGE_DIRECTION, MESSAGE_STATUS, MESSAGE_LOCAL_STATUS, MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP};
    String selection = MESSAGE_SENDER_ID + "=?" + " AND " + MESSAGE_RECIPIENT_ID + "=?" + " OR " + MESSAGE_SENDER_ID + "=?" + " AND " + MESSAGE_RECIPIENT_ID + "=?";
    String [] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(senderId), String.valueOf(recipientId), String.valueOf(recipientId), String.valueOf(senderId)};
    String orderBy = ID + " DESC";
    String limit = "50";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_MESSAGES, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy, limit);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //cursor reading stuff
    }
```

Mentioned code is working as expected as I want. It gets last 50 records but the problem is, it gets last 50 records in desc order. Lets suppose I have record from 1 to 100 numbers in sequence. My code first changes its order (because query has desc clause)that means record will be in sequence of 100 to 1 and "limit 50" clause gets first 50 record. And now here is the problem
now my record will be 100,99,98,,,and last record would be 51 but i want my records in asc order as it was originally in asc in DB(Record should be fetched as 51,52 and so on till 100). I have some solution for this as well. I know I can do sorting stuff from java comparator.My question is there any better way to solve this problem?Or any sqlite query that can solve the same problem rather fetching data and after populating sorting stuff.

Comment: Slightly pedantic, but important point: you say "_as it was originally in asc in DB_". Inside the database _there is no order_ -- just a collection of rows. Ordering only happens during `SELECT` and _only_ if an `ORDER BY` clause is used. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, you _cannot_ rely on the order returned (however repeatable it might seem) -- different decisions by the query planner, the presence of different indices etc. may all alter an un-ordered `SELECT` (an SQL engine is even _allowed_ to randomise the order each time, if it wanted).

Comment: @TripeHound yes i said asc in DB because I am fetching record according to primary key that is auto incremented. The more records user adds they can be organized asc and desc according to primary key

Answer (score 2):

You have to use one ordering for the LIMIT, and another ordering for the result. So you need a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ...
      ...
      ORDER BY ID DESC
      LIMIT 50)
ORDER BY ID;
```

To be able to execute this, you have to use [rawQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) instead.

Comment: is it possible to do same thing without rawQuery()? How about if I use query method as i mentioned in my code? What I guess the performance of query() method is better the rawQuery() method. Pardon me if i am wrong

Comment: You could try to stuff the entire subquery into the `table` parameter, but that would be silly.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (select [COLUMN_NAME] from [TABLE_NAME] order by ID DESC limit 50) order by ID ASC;
```

Inner select query will select the **last** 50 records so the sort order is **DESC**.
And outer select query will select all the records queried by inner select and sort it in ascending order so **ASC** is needed.

Comment: Please explain your answer better. A good answer explains the content, it doesn't just show a line of code